# How do I use the .send method for a dynamic class to go to the specific path in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, send

I am using the following:

```
send("#{done_event.class.name.tableize}_path", done_event.id)
```

An example is done_event is a specific instance of ContactEmail.

I would like this to represent the path contact_email_path(done_event.id) which would translate to something like contact_emails/1

However, the result I get is contact_emails.1

Not sure what to do...?

I also get this error when I just try to pass in the object:

```
http://localhost:3000/contact_calls.%23%3Ccontactcall:0x9fefb80%3E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
send("#{done_event.class.name.tableize.singularize}_path", done_event)
```

although if the polymorphic worked, i would like to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
eval("#{done_event.class.to_s.underscore}_path(done_event)")
```

Comment: what's teh diff between eval versus send, which si what I was using?

Comment: nopt, doesn't work...it evalutes done_event as an object, so it comes out contact_email.<object>

Comment: Then just put the id instead: eval("#{done_event.class.to_s.underscore}_path(#{done_event.id})")

Comment: Yannis, thx :) I couldn't get it to work with send method, moreover your comment helped as well >> `eval("show_reply_#{model_name}_comment_path(#{model_variable.id}, #{comment.id})")`

Answer (score 0):

Try [polymorphic_url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url) like this

```
polymorphic_url([:contact_emails, done_event])
```

EDIT: Since you don't know the class of 'done_event', all you have to do is pass like this.

```
polymorphic_url(done_event)
```

Comment: but I don't know whether it is contadt_emails or contadt-calls ...that's why it's dynamic

Comment: It will still be fine. Just pass the class name you like

Comment: Sorry I have pressed the wrong key.. I was saying that you should try passing the class name in the method like
polymorphic_url([done_event.class.name, done_event])
You might need to make the class name plural to make it work. It's worth testing it, I guess.

Comment: I will try that ... I did get it to work using send, its messier what is the interpretation of polymorphic_url -- does it mean it will take the first arg and call that the arg_path and the second is passed in?

Comment: Please check my edited answer for that. If you ever need to generate a url/path dynamically when you don't know the class of the object, you should just use polymorphic_url. e.g. polymorphic_url(post) # => "http://example.com/posts/1"